# Setup of secure BLE connection for ESP32

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

I need to put a password for BLE connection of ESP32. Namely, I need to create a password as an array, and every time I need to connect my phone I will enter it. System will check if password is correct and then let me make an action (for now it is just control over LED). I searched for a solution but couldn't find anything similar. I only know that I should somehow use EEPROM. I put basic code which includes actions appart from password.

```
const byte led_gpio = 32;
int LED_BUILTIN = 2;
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
pinMode(led_gpio, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  
  if (ESP_BT.available()) //Check if we receive anything from Bluetooth
  {
    if (ESP_BT.read()== PASSWORD)
    {
    incoming = ESP_BT.read(); //Read what we recevive 
    Serial.print("Received:"); Serial.println(incoming);

    if (incoming == 48)
        {
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(led_gpio, HIGH);
        
        ESP_BT.println("LED turned ON");
        }
        
    if (incoming == 49)
        {
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
        ESP_BT.println("LED turned OFF");
        digitalWrite(led_gpio, LOW); 
        }     
  }
  }
  delay(20);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are using BluetoothSerial to communicate with your phone. BluetoothSerial is a library for Bluetooth Classic connections but you used the Tag for Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE). Which one would you like to use?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I used the code for Bluetooth classic connection previously. But now it needs to be BLE connection with password. I attached the code just to explain what I want to do.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to send a password via BLE? Keep in mind that it is quite easy to sniff bluetooth traffic and read such password.

Comment: No, I want to make a connection so that only people who know password can connect to it. Let's say password is 123456, when client scans Bluetooth he sees my ESP32 but he enters password and only then he can send or receive data.

Comment: This is not the standard way of doing BLE security and might require you to develop your own security layer on top of BLE. Take a look at the usual way to do security in BLE here: https://medium.com/rtone-iot-security/deep-dive-into-bluetooth-le-security-d2301d640bfc#:~:text=and%20secure%20connections.-,Pairing%20Procedures,-A%20pairing%20procedure The different pairing procedures depend on the actual I/O capabilities of your device

Comment: Thank you for the link you shared. It was informative. Maybe you have a piece of code (Arduino IDE) for BLE pairing? Task is to connect the smartphone to ESP32 after authentication and send ON/OFF signal to LED connected to ESP32.

Comment: You can try something like this: https://github.com/choichangjun/ESP32_arduino/blob/master/ESP32_Arduino_paring_Key.ino I'm not sure if it is up to date

Comment: I tried this code, it doesn't work.  I was told that I need to use EEPROM read function and create a loop to check each element of array whether it satisfies password or not but I have no idea how it should look like.

Answer (score 1):

see this example:

https://github.com/nkolban/esp32-snippets/blob/master/cpp_utils/tests/BLETests/Arduino/security/StaticPIN/StaticPIN.ino

```
/*
  Based on Neil Kolban example for IDF: https://github.com/nkolban/esp32- snippets/blob/master/cpp_utils/tests/BLE%20Tests/SampleServer.cpp
Ported to Arduino ESP32 by Evandro Copercini
*/

#include <BLEDevice.h>
#include <BLEUtils.h>
#include <BLEServer.h>

// See the following for generating UUIDs:
// https://www.uuidgenerator.net/

#define SERVICE_UUID        "4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b"
#define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID "beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8"

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Starting BLE work!");

  BLEDevice::init("ESP32");
  /*
   * Required in authentication process to provide displaying and/or input passkey or yes/no butttons confirmation
   */
  BLEServer *pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();
  BLEService *pService = pServer->createService(SERVICE_UUID);
  BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
                                         CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
                                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ |
                                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE
                                       );
  pCharacteristic->setAccessPermissions(ESP_GATT_PERM_READ_ENCRYPTED | ESP_GATT_PERM_WRITE_ENCRYPTED);
  pCharacteristic->setValue("Hello World says Neil");
  pService->start();
  BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = pServer->getAdvertising();
  pAdvertising->start();

  BLESecurity *pSecurity = new BLESecurity();
  pSecurity->setStaticPIN(123456); 

  //set static passkey
  Serial.println("Characteristic defined! Now you can read it in your phone!");
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  delay(2000);
}
```

Comment: Note though that a static passkey instead of a random one is extremely insecure due to the protocol design, as you can see at https://insinuator.net/2021/10/change-your-ble-passkey-like-you-change-your-underwear/. Furthermore, the access permissions must be `ESP_GATT_PERM_READ_ENC_MITM`, `ESP_GATT_PERM_WRITE_ENC_MITM` to disallow JustWorks pairing (otherwise the passkey can be bypassed entirely). To properly secure a BLE device using a "password", you must use a PAKE (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password-authenticated_key_agreement) since the BLE security simply does not support this.